# Creating Logic Trees to be Exported to Word

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, logic, prooftrees

I'm trying to typeset a book on logic which will be published soon. It contains a lot of logic trees, truth tables etc. The problem is publisher wants it to be Word file, therefore I can't get the whole job done with latex. I tried to export the trees as png to insert it to the Word but printing quality is horrible. I tried to exporting from pdf to word as text but exported text either wrong or breaks as soon as I touch the file. The codes, and trees I will share you with is from Hodges' "Logic" since I can't share the book I'm typesetting due to legal reasons.

```
\documentclass[10pt, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
&\forall x ((Mx \wedge Cx) \rightarrow \forall y(Py \rightarrow Sxy)).\; \exists x Px.\\
&\forall x((Cx \wedge \exists y(Py \wedge Sxy)) \rightarrow Bx).\; (Mb \wedge Cb).\\
&\textit{Therefore}\; Bb.
\end{align*}
\begin{center}
%    \textbf{Tableaux:}\\
    \begin{prooftree}
        {
            %to prove={
            %\forall x ((Mx \wedge Cx) \rightarrow \forall y(Py \rightarrow Sxy)).\, \exists x Px.\,
            %\forall x((Cx \wedge \exists y(Py \wedge Sxy)) \rightarrow Bx).\, (Mb \wedge Cb).\,
            %\textit{Therefore}\, Bb.}
        }
        [\forall x ((Mx \wedge Cx) \rightarrow \forall y (Py \rightarrow Sxy))
            [\exists xPx
                [\forall x((Cx \wedge \exists y(Py \wedge Sxy)) \rightarrow Bx)
                    [(Mb \wedge Cb)
                        [\lnot Bb
                            [((Mb \wedge Cb) \rightarrow \forall y(Py \rightarrow Sby))
                                [\lnot (Mb \wedge Cb), close]
                                [\forall y(Py \rightarrow Sby)
                                    [Pd
                                        [Pd \rightarrow Sbd
                                            [\lnot Pd, close]
                                            [Sbd
                                                [((Cb \wedge \exists y(Py \wedge Sby)) \rightarrow Bb)
                                                    [\lnot (Cb \wedge \exists y(Py \wedge Sby))
                                                        [\lnot Cb  
                                                            [Mb
                                                                [Cb, close]
                                                            ]
                                                        ]
                                                        [\lnot \exists y(Py \wedge Sby)
                                                            [\forall y \lnot (Py \wedge Sby)
                                                                [\lnot (Pd \wedge Sbd)
                                                                    [\lnot Pd, close]
                                                                    [\lnot Sbd, close]
                                                                ]
                                                            ]
                                                        ]
                                                    ]
                                                [\lnot Bb,close]]]]]]]]]]]]
    \end{prooftree}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And this is how it looks in a word file:
[image]

Difference is pretty clear I think. I also made one with *tikz* but it's not any better.

```
\documentclass[10pt, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5ex]
    %CONTENT
    \node   (a)                                         {$\forall x(x=b \iff (Mx \wedge Cx))$};
    \node   (b)   [below=of a]                          {$\forall x(Cx \rightarrow (Bx \iff Mx))$};
    \node   (c)   [below=of b]                          {$\lnot \forall x(x=b \iff (Cx \wedge Bx))$};
    \node   (d)   [below=of c]                          {$\exists x \lnot (x=b \iff (Cx \wedge Bx))$};
    \node   (e)   [below=of d]                          {$\lnot (d=b \iff (Cd \wedge Bd))$};
    \node   (f)   [below left=of e, xshift=10mm]        {$d=b$};
    \node   (g)   [below right=of e, xshift=-10mm]      {$\lnot d=b$};
    \node   (fa)    [below=of f]                        {$\lnot (Cd \wedge Bd)$};
    \node   (fb)    [below=of fa]                       {$\lnot (Cd \wedge Bb)$};
    \node   (fc)    [below=of fb]                       {$(b=b \iff (Mb \wedge Cb))$};
    \node   (ga)    [below=of g]                        {$(Cd \wedge Bd)$};
    \node   (gb)    [below=of ga]                       {$Cd$};
    \node   (gc)    [below=of gb]                       {$Bd$};
    \node   (gd)    [below=of gc, xshift=10mm]          {$(Cd \rightarrow (Bd \iff Md))$};
    \node   (fcla)    [below left=of fc, xshift=10mm]   {$b=b$};
    \node   (fclb)    [below=of fcla]                   {$(Mb \wedge Cb)$};
    \node   (fclc)    [below=of fclb]                   {$Mb$};
    \node   (fcld)    [below=of fclc]                   {$Cb$};
    \node   (fcle)    [below=of fcld, xshift=3mm]       {$(Cb \rightarrow (Bb \iff Mb))$};
    \node   (fcra)    [below right=of fc, xshift=-20mm] {$\lnot b = b$};
    \node   (fcrb)    [below=of fcra]                   {\underline{$\lnot (Mb \wedge Cb)$}}; %You'll close this!!!
    \node   (fclea)   [below left=of fcle, xshift=10mm] {\underline{$\lnot Cb$}}; %You'll close this.
    \node   (fcleb)   [below right=of fcle, xshift=-10mm] {$(Bb \iff Mb)$};
    \node   (fcleba)    [below left=of fcleb, xshift=10mm]{$Bb$};
    \node   (fclebb)    [below=of fcleba]                 {$Mb$};
    \node   (fclebc)    [below right=of fcleb, xshift=-10mm]{$\lnot Bb$};
    \node   (fclebd)    [below=of fclebc]                   {\underline{$\lnot Mb$}}; %You'll close this.
    \node   (fclebba)    [below left=of fclebb, xshift=1mm] {\underline{$\lnot Cb$}}; %CLOSE
    \node   (fclebbb)    [below right=of fclebb, xshift=0mm]{\underline{$\lnot Bb$}}; %CLOSE
    \node   (gda)    [below left=of gd, xshift=10mm]        {\underline{$\lnot Cd$}}; %CLOSE
    \node   (gdb)    [below right=of gd, xshift=-20mm]      {$(Bd \iff Md)$};
    \node   (gdbra)    [below right=of gdb, xshift=-10mm]   {$\lnot Bd$};
    \node   (gdbrb)    [below=of gdbra]                     {\underline{$\lnot Md$}}; %CLOSE
    \node   (gdlaa)    [below left=of gdb, xshift=10mm]     {$Bd$};
    \node   (gdlab)    [below=of gdlaa]                     {$Md$};
    \node   (gdlac)    [below=of gdlab, xshift=-2mm]        {$(d = b \iff (Md \wedge Cd))$};
    \node   (lg)    [below left=of gdlac, xshift=10mm]      {$d=b$};
    \node   (lga)    [below=of lg]                          {\underline{$(Md \wedge Cd)$}}; % Close
    \node   (rg)    [below right=of gdlac, xshift=-10mm]    {$\lnot d=b$};
    \node   (rga)    [below=of rg]                          {$\lnot (Md \wedge Cd)$};
    \node   (rgal)    [below left=of rga, xshift=10mm]      {\underline{$\lnot Md$}}; %CLOSE
    \node   (rgar)    [below right=of rga, xshift=-10mm]    {\underline{$\lnot Cd$}}; %CLOSE
    %PATHS
    \path (f) edge[-] (e);
    \path (g) edge[-] (e);
    \path (fcla) edge[-] (fc);
    \path (fcra) edge[-] (fc);
    \path (fclea) edge[-] (fcle);
    \path (fcleb) edge[-] (fcle);
    \path (fcleba) edge[-] (fcleb);
    \path (fclebc) edge[-] (fcleb);
    \path (fclebba) edge[-] (fclebb);
    \path (fclebbb) edge[-] (fclebb);
    \path (gda) edge[-] (gd);
    \path (gdb) edge[-] (gd);
    \path (gdbra) edge[-] (gdb);
    \path (gdlaa) edge[-] (gdb);
    \path (lg) edge[-] (gdlac);
    \path (rg) edge[-] (gdlac);
    \path (rgal) edge[-] (rga);
    \path (rgar) edge[-] (rga);
    %LINE NUMBERS
    \node (1) [left=3cm of a] {1.};
    \node (2) at (1 |- b) {2.};
    \node (3) at (1 |- c) {3.};        
    \node (4) at (1 |- d) {4.};
    \node (5) at (1 |- e) {5.};
    \node (6) at (1 |- f) {6.};
    \node (7) at (1 |- fa) {7.};    
    \node (8) at (1 |- fb) {8.};    
    \node (9) at (1 |- fc) {9.};    
    \node (10) at (1 |- fcla) {10.};    
    \node (11) at (1 |- fclb) {11.};    
    \node (12) at (1 |- fclc) {12.};    
    \node (13) at (1 |- fcld) {13.};    
    \node (14) at (1 |- fcle) {14.};    
    \node (15) at (1 |- fclea) {15.};    
    \node (16) at (1 |- fcleba) {16.};    
    \node (17) at (1 |- fclebb) {17.};    
    \node (18) at (1 |- fclebba) {18.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

So, how can I make them look pretty and worth to publish in a Word file? And as a bonus question how can I make the branches as a cornered straight line instead of these diagonal lines?

Comment: The problem rather seems that Word can't handle PDF files that are pasted directly into the document and probably converts them into low-resolution PNG or JPEG. I would probably just export to PDF and then tell the publisher where to put which diagram. If they want Word, they need to cope with such complications, because Word is just not a DTP software for high quality printing. Another way could be to create high-resolution PNGs or JPEGs from the exported PDFs which you then should be able to paste into the Word file without probelms (but the final file will probably be huge).

Comment: @JasperHabicht I did that. I mean these are the high-resolution PNGs which I printed with acrobat and used the highest settings possible. They look perfect outside Word but as soon as I insert them or copy paste them into the Word they look like this.

Comment: I see, but then, it is not really a TeX question but a Word question, isn't it? I do think that it is possible to paste high-resolution graphics into a Word file, but I currently don't remember what setting is relevant for this.

Comment: Did you check the image quality settings in the Word options (File > Options > Advanced > Image Size and Quality: https://i.stack.imgur.com/68Q2z.png )? Maybe this helps, but not 100% sure.

Comment: @JasperHabicht not the quality I seek for but it looks way better. Thank you for help. Do you know about the branches? Like how can I make them look like this: https://imgur.com/BOOyO7E

Comment: Have you asked the publisher how they plan to accommodate requests for accessibility if your tableaux are PNGs? What do you mean by 'cornered straight line'? If you tell me, I can probably tell you how to have `prooftrees` do it. Incidentally, `prooftrees` is basically Ti*k*Z, so I wouldn't expect quality differences on export.

Comment: You have an error on line 12, by the way: not-Bb should be Bb. About the lines do you mean what `forest` calls `forked edges`?

Comment: @cfr Yes, you are right I misread it. Thank you for spotting it. I guess it's called forked edges but I'm not 100% sure. I shared the image of it in my previous comment, I'd be glad if you can check it.

Comment: @arkh3us There's an example on page 5 of `prooftrees`'s manual. You can find the code in `prooftrees.tex`, which is part of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forest` provides a style of branches called `forked edges` as part of the `edges` library. Because `prooftrees` loads `forest`, you either need to load `forest` first or use the separate macro to load the library. The following example demonstrates the former method. It also shows how to accommodate a multiline `to prove` statement, though I'm wondering if `prooftrees` should offer a ready-made option for this.

```
\documentclass[10pt, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{prooftrees}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
    {
      to prove={
        $\forall x ((Mx \wedge Cx) \rightarrow \forall y(Py \rightarrow Sxy)).\, \exists x Px.$\\
        $\forall x((Cx \wedge \exists y(Py \wedge Sxy)) \rightarrow Bx).\, (Mb \wedge Cb).$\\
        $\textit{Therefore}\, Bb.$},
      proof statement format'={align=l,anchor=south},
      forked edges,
    }
    [\forall x ((Mx \wedge Cx) \rightarrow \forall y (Py \rightarrow Sxy))
        [\exists xPx
            [\forall x((Cx \wedge \exists y(Py \wedge Sxy)) \rightarrow Bx)
                [(Mb \wedge Cb)
                    [\lnot Bb
                        [((Mb \wedge Cb) \rightarrow \forall y(Py \rightarrow Sby))
                            [\lnot (Mb \wedge Cb), close]
                            [\forall y(Py \rightarrow Sby)
                                [Pd
                                    [Pd \rightarrow Sbd
                                        [\lnot Pd, close]
                                        [Sbd
                                            [((Cb \wedge \exists y(Py \wedge Sby)) \rightarrow Bb)
                                                [\lnot (Cb \wedge \exists y(Py \wedge Sby))
                                                    [\lnot Cb  
                                                        [Mb
                                                            [Cb, close]
                                                        ]
                                                    ]
                                                    [\lnot \exists y(Py \wedge Sby)
                                                        [\forall y \lnot (Py \wedge Sby)
                                                            [\lnot (Pd \wedge Sbd)
                                                                [\lnot Pd, close]
                                                                [\lnot Sbd, close]
                                                            ]
                                                        ]
                                                    ]
                                                ]
                                            [Bb,close]]]]]]]]]]]]
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image: tableau with 'forked edges']

Comment: You are an angel. Thank you so much. I was tearing out my hair because of multiline problem with "to prove". I used "\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}" for newer files but it was nothing but a noisy code. Thank you again.

Comment: @arkh3us That's not good. I think there should be an option for this. If you have a lot of tableaux which need this, you can also change the format of the proof statement globally. You just need to remember the dollar signs (because we're using the `tabular` provided by `forest` rather than a specialist maths environment such as `align*`).

Comment: I wonder if I could persuade `forest` to use something like `align*` for the node ....